# Onclick toggle DIV class

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I have a button that is a div class, lets call it "login-button-arrow".
I want to set up a javascript method, so when this div gets clicked on, a little javascript box can pop up.

How do I go about doing this?
I have tried something like this:

```
login-button-arrow.onclick{alert('xyz')}
```

but I guess it does not work like that.

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial about DOM event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Get #popup element:
const popup = document.querySelector("#popup");

// Function to toggle popup (toggles .active) 
const togglePopup = () => {
  console.log( "xyz" );
  popup.classList.toggle("active"); 
};

// Get buttons elements from DOM
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.login-button-arrow');

// Assign event listener with callback to every button:
buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", togglePopup);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.login-button-arrow').on('click', function() { alert('xyz'); });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var login-button-arrows = document.getElementsByClassName('login-button-arrow');

login-button-arrows.forEach(function(obj){
    obj.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('xyz');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

using Jquery :

> $('#login-button-arrow').on('click', function(){ alert('xyz'); });

Comment: This is `id` selector you're using

Comment: OP didn't specify if it was a class or else. He just mentioned 'DIV class' which is confusing.

Comment: @Eric questions that clearly state [tag:javascript] should be answered in JavaScript, not jQuery. We need to provide answers exclusively related to the **tagged language**, not by a exo-pseudo-language library. I'm not saying "Use jQuery" is a bad suggestion, just, *it was not a Question*. People browsing for such or similar Q in javascript get frustrated by seeing answers in jQuery which they don't need. Hope I this was helpful